# Error when run LD_PRELOAD with boost

Tags: c++, boost, ld-preload

I compiled LD_PRELOAD which uses boost (locks.hpp). Compile was successfull. I copied this LD_PRELOAD to other linux server, and when i run, error:

> /usr/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /test/test.so: undefined symbol:
>   _ZN5boost11this_thread20disable_interruptionC1Ev

How can i fix this? Can i avoid this problem without installing boost on this server?

How i compile LD_PRELOAD:

```
g++ -fPIC -m32  -shared -Wl,-soname,test.so -ldl -o test.so test.cpp
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to get `libboost_thread` into your `test.so` file. Something along the lines of:

```
g++ -fPIC -m32  -shared -Wl,-soname,test.so -ldl -o test.so test.cpp \ 
  /usr/lib/libboost_thread.a -lpthread
```

Since I wouldn't know the specifics for your system, the boost library might be in a different place than from mine.

Comment: i cant find BOOST_PATH and BOOST_PLATFORM can you help me how can i find it?

Comment: @Robert: I don't know where boost would be installed on your system, but I modifed the answer to reflect where it is on mine.